# double integral with sin

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the iterated integral

[image]

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out. I was wondering if I need to use substitution with u and du. I am not really sure how to start it off, any help would be amazing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With double integrals (and double sums), the first place to start is often to switch the order of integration:
$$\begin{align} \int_0^2 \int_{x^2}^4 x^3 \sin(y^3) \, dy \, dx &= \int_0^4 \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} x^3 \sin(y^3) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_0^4 \sin(y^3)\left[\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^\sqrt{y} \, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^4y^2\sin(y^3)\,dy\end{align}$$

It should be clearer from here!

(Switching the order of integration is justified by Fubini's theorem - $|x^3 \sin(y^3)|$ is continuous and bounded on $[0,2]\times[0,4]$).

Comment: I did not see that! that makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: I have actually noticed that the second integral is from 0 to √y

Comment: My mistake, fixed.